# How to create searchbar which will search over the JSON in listview

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have search bar which show empty listview when i write something in it, deserialization in ItemPage and SearchBar_TextChanged. Whole file looks like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Diabetics.Models;
using Diabetics.ViewModels;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Plugin.Connectivity;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Diabetics.Views
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class ItemPage : ContentPage
    {

        public ObservableCollection<Item> itemlist = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public ItemPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAll();

            ItemsListView.RefreshCommand = new Command(() => {
                LoadAll();
                ItemsListView.IsRefreshing = false;
            });

        }

        private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
            {
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist.Where(x => x.Nazwa.Contains(e.NewTextValue)).ToList();
            }
        }

        async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!(args.SelectedItem is Item item))
                return;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(item.Nazwa, item.Opis, item.Zdjecie, item.WW, item.WBT, item.Energia, item.Tluszcz, item.Weglowodany, item.Blonnik, item.Bialko, item.Zelazo, item.Wapn));

            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }

        private async void ToolbarItem_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new FullScreenScanning());
        }

        private async void LoadAll()
        {
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
            waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                HttpClient Klient = new HttpClient();
                Klient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://next.json-generator.com");
                string url = string.Format("/api/json/get/4yvwrz2bd");
                var response = await Klient.GetAsync(url);
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", string.Format("Musisz być podłączony do internetu", ex.Message), "OK");
                waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            }
            waitActivityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
            waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
            var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);
            ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
        }


    } 
}
```

Mine searchbar in XAML looks like this `<SearchBar Text="" Placeholder="Wyszukaj..." TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" x:Name="searchbarnew"/>`
I want it to show Items which have same **Nazwa** as  e.NewTextValue mine Json File looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Nazwa": "Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness",
    "Opis": "Przykładowy opis produktu Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness",
    "Zdjecie": "https://www.friars.co.uk/images/lindt-gold-milk-chocolate-bar-p504-7263_image.jpg",
    "WW": 0.28,
    "WBT": 0.22,
    "Energia": 31.8125,
    "Tluszcz": 2.19375,
    "Weglowodany": 3.225,
    "Blonnik": 0.11875,
    "Bialko": 0.45625,
    "Zelazo": 0.1875,
    "Wapn": 15.5
  },
  {
    "Nazwa": "Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness2",
    "Opis": "Przykładowy opis produktu Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness2",
    "Zdjecie": "https://vaya.in/recipes/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Milk-Chocolate-1.jpg",
    "WW": 0.16,
    "WBT": 0.21,
    "Energia": 28.5625,
    "Tluszcz": 2.19375,
    "Weglowodany": 2.94375,
    "Blonnik": 0.4875,
    "Bialko": 0.34375,
    "Zelazo": 0.8125,
    "Wapn": 0
  }
]
```

It has to show items which have same name as e.NewTextValue for example if we search for **Fitness2** it should show only one list item. Now its empty and I theres no error.

Comment: have you done anything to attempt to debug this?  Step through the code in the debugger?  Verify that `itemlist` actually contains data?

Comment: if you mean this ```var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);``` then yes it contains data because its showed in app but only when i start writing something its empty

Comment: have you stepped through `SearchBar_TextChanged` to verify that you LINQ query is working?

Comment: That's how it looks in app https://imgur.com/a/m5ZnHgA

Comment: @Jason how I can verify that?

Comment: use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint in that function and step through it.

Comment: I put breakpoint after else on that line ```var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);``` and app freeze

Comment: okay i think thats an Error https://imgur.com/a/3ORvSHl

Comment: Okay itemlist in SearchBar_TextChanged has no value (i think) https://imgur.com/a/lX2YJLO
so i think i need to call ```var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);``` this from LoadAll() to SearchBar_TextChanged. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are redeclaring `itemlist` as a local variable instead of using the class level variable that already exists

```
 waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
 var itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);
 ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
```

remove the `var`

```
 waitActivityIndicator.IsVisible = false;
 itemlist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Item>>(result);
 ItemsListView.ItemsSource = itemlist;
```